# AutoMapper relations between two entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, automapper, asp.net-core-6.0

I have two entity models in my ASP.NET Core 6 application:

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; } = null!;
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public int? FKIdClassEmployee { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ClassEmployee? ClassEmployee { get; set; }
}

public partial class ClassEmployee
{
    public ClassEmployee()
    {
        Employee = new HashSet<Employee>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Label { get; set; }
    public decimal? Cost { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

In the `EmployeeController`, I'm try to use AutoMapper to map `ClassEmployee` to an existing record.

This is my Automapper config:

```
public class EmployeeProfile : Profile
{
    private readonly ApplicationContext _ctx;

    public EmployeeProfile(ApplicationContext ctx)
    {
        _ctx = ctx;
        EmployeeDTOToEmployee();
    }

    private void EmployeeDTOToEmployee()
    {
        CreateMap<EmployeeDTO, Employee>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.SerialNumber, opt => opt.MapFrom(d => d.SerialNumber))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Active, opt => opt.MapFrom(d => d.Active))
            .ForMember(dest => FKIdClassEmployee, opt => opt.MapFrom(d => d.FKIdClassEmployee))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ClassEmployee, opt => opt.MapFrom(
                src => _ctx.ClassEmployee.Find(src.FKIdClassEmployee)));
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work because it returns an error

> Duplicate key value violates unique constraint

when it is called the `Create` method.

Comment: Sometimes it's easier just to manually map it!

Comment: @GHDevOps I know, but it's a request from my Senior...

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/issues/141#issuecomment-1079914176 Also, the first three `MapFrom`s are useless. You _really_ need to learn to use AM properly.

Comment: What "Create method" do you mean?

Comment: @godot Create method in api EmployeeController, it the simple

Comment: so it seems EF error message or some ORM, the issue not in mapping I suppose

Comment: Ignore mapping of ID and there will not be problem, I think @SerPecchia

Comment: You say You want to map ClassEmployee but in the example, You are mapping Employee, also can You share DTO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all involving `DbContext` in mapping configuration isn't a good idea (in my opinion). Use Lazy, Eager or Explicit loading instead. If a pair of Model (Entity) and Dto has same property name and type you don't have to specify  `.ForMemeber(dest => dest..., opt => opt.MapFrom(...))`  . For nested mapping just configure all Entities and Dtos.
Configuration should look like this:

```
// NOTE: Same property type and name will be mapped

// Map Dto values to Entity
CreateMap<EmployeeDTO, Employee>();
CreateMap<ClassEmployeeDTO, ClassEmployee>();

// Map Entity values to Dto
CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeDTO>();
CreateMap<ClassEmployee, ClassEmployeeDTO>();
```

Comment: You can create two-way mapping with `ReverseMap()` configuration.

Comment: Yes, but `ReverseMap` tries to reverse the configuration and that can get complicated quickly. Unless you're experienced with AM, separate maps are a lot easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have still the problem that i can't associate ClassEmployee object to my class Employee

Comment: Configure mapping for inner class property too, dto and model properties' should be same not to explicitly configure or you have to configure different properties.